# Rigging Eyelids using drivers

Tags: rigging

Been following Level Pixel Level Rigging of eyelids and I am stuck on getting the controller to drive the eyelid shut. When I cut and paste the data path to the eyelid bone, I don't get "Location" is the data path but only "Rotation". What is the solution here?

[image]

Comment: have you tried `rotation_euler[2]`. even easier is just right click the property you want as driver and select *Copy as New Driver* then go to the property you want to be driven and right click *Paste Driver*

Comment: Could you attach your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com